# Anti-aliasing with FXAAShader doesn't look good on wireframes

Tags: three.js

I basically followed [this](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=fxaa#webgl_postprocessing_fxaa) examples to set up anti-aliasing with the help of the `FXAAShader` like this:

```js
this.composer = new EffectComposer(this.renderer);
const renderPass = new RenderPass(this.scene, this.camera);

this.fxaaPass = new ShaderPass(FXAAShader);
const pixelRatio = this.renderer.getPixelRatio();
const uniforms = this.fxaaPass.material.uniforms;
uniforms['resolution'].value.x = 1 / (this.canvas.offsetWidth * pixelRatio);
uniforms['resolution'].value.y = 1 / (this.canvas.offsetHeight * pixelRatio);

this.composer.addPass(renderPass);
this.composer.addPass(this.fxaaPass);
```

and this is how I render the wireframe

```js
const mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x000000,
  linewidth: 2,
});
const geo = new THREE.WireframeGeometry(this.geometry);
this.wireframeGroup = new THREE.Group();
const wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments(geo, mat);
this.wireframeGroup.add(wireframe);
const solid = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
const base = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, solid);
this.wireframeGroup.add(base);
this.scene.add(this.wireframeGroup);
```

But the result looks kind of "pixly"
[image: wireframe composer]

However, when use the normal `rendere` (not the `composer`), anti-aliasing seems to work fine:
[image: wireframe normal renderer]

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/drakery3d/experimental-3dviewer/blob/d0be888f7013b16e6fa7d604285103d660f0e40d/viewer/src/app/viewer.component.ts#L158)

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. FXAA is simply not as good at anti-aliasing as the default `renderer.antialias = true` method (which often defaults to MSAA, but it could vary depending on the GPU). The example in threejs.org is a little misleading because the red pyramids are constantly in motion, which doesn't give your eyes a chance to see the jaggies. You can read more about it [in this discussion](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/what-aa-method-does-antialias-true-use/15146/5).

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. So do I have any chance getting better anti-aliasing while using the composer? :)

Comment: I found that using [`renderer.setPixelRatio(1.5)`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setPixelRatio) works as a quick and easy supsersampling method, without fully quadrupling the number of pixels, although it still comes at a higher performance cost. If you're using Webgl2, you could also use [MultisampleRenderTarget](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLMultisampleRenderTarget), which gives you the same AA quality as when rendering directly to canvas.

Comment: The MSAA is what I needed, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help. Just make sure your audience has WebGL2 support, because all Apple products and IE11 still don't support it: https://caniuse.com/#search=webgl2

Comment: Glad you brought that up! I'll probably use a fallback for those devices